# How to change ImageView images using OnLongClickListener and Save State using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onlongclicklistener

I am new to Android development. I'm doing it with Kotlin.
I got an assignment to change the imageView image using OnLongClickListener like changing two to three images every long press. also, I want to save the state of the images after the rotating screen. I set it up for changing one image to another for one time but still confused how to do it properly.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    lightMe.setOnLongClickListener {
        lightMe.run {

            lightMe.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_flare_24))
            lightMe.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_wb_incandescent_24))
                true
        }
    }

}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example. I have added one `ImageView` and I am changing the image on a long click.

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val IMAGE_ID_KEY = "IMAGE_ID_KEY" //key to save imageId
    }

    @DrawableRes
    private var imageId = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground //field which keeps actual drawable id
        set(value) {
            field = value
            image.setImageResource(value) //every time value is changed, ImageView is updated
        }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d("MY_TAG", "onCreate")

        image.setOnLongClickListener {
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "longClick")
            // change image to the opposite
            imageId =
                if (imageId == R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground else R.drawable.ic_launcher_background
            
            true
        }
    }

    // saving imageId before app can be destroyed. E.g. rotation
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "onSaveInstanceState")
        outState.putInt(IMAGE_ID_KEY, imageId)
    }

    // restoring imageId every time app is recreating
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "onRestoreInstanceState")
        imageId = savedInstanceState.getInt(IMAGE_ID_KEY)
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml (just an image):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @iknow bro it worked for two images but if I need to change more than two images how can I change the listener logic?

Comment: It will work in the same way. E.g. You have 7 images: Create `val actualIndex: Int = 0` and every time You long click do `actualIndex+=1; actualIndex%=7;`. In the setter of `actualIndex` do simple logic `if(value==0) image.SetImageResource(ID_OF_1ST_IMAGE)` etc. And know You don't have to save resourceId but just a `actualIndex`